# Group by an advanced way

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I ran into a bit of a problem when trying to do a query to group messages into conversations.
So that messages with same sender and receiver will be in the same conversation.
As well there will be group conversations, which means two and two persons talk together as four.

My database table looks like this:

Table: `messages`

```
+----+------+----+---------+---------+
| id | from | to | group_1 | group_2 |
+----+------+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1    | 2  | 0       | 0       |
| 2  | 2    | 1  | 0       | 0       |
| 3  | 1    | 0  | 1       | 2       |
| 4  | 2    | 0  | 2       | 1       |
| 5  | 3    | 0  | 1       | 2       |
| 6  | 4    | 0  | 2       | 1       |
| 7  | 4    | 1  | 0       | 0       |
| 8  | 1    | 4  | 0       | 0       |
+----+------+----+---------+---------+
```

I have tried with the following, but then I get all the messages out, so I need to make a group by, to make them stick into one row instead of having multiple rows for same conversation.

SELECT * FROM `messages`

So basically what is needed to be done, is to group by the following:
 - Group rows conversations where `from` and `to` is equals with other rows, while `group_1` and `group_2` = 0. But also it should group those rows where `to` is equal with other rows `from`, and the other way around, but still while `group_1` and `group_2` = 0. (Like the 2 first rows in the table above)
 - Group rows conversations where `group_1` and `group_2` is equals with other rows, while `to` = 0, and as well where `group_1` is equal with other rows `group_2`, and the other way around, but still while `to` = 0. (Like the rows with id 3 and 4)

So basically it should group all messages where groups are talking with each other, and where users are talking with each other.

EDIT

## Better explaining of `group_1` and `group_2`

`group_1` and `group_2` is made so that I can put a user inside a group, and make a group able to talk with another group.

So instead of using `to` and `from`, then they use `group_1` and `group_2`.
It should GROUP the group conversations just like the user conversations (where `from` and `to` are defined).

You can see that a row is a group, when `to = 0`. When `to != 0`, then it is not a group.

It should GROUP `group_1` and `group_2`, just like users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is my proposal;**

```
SELECT * FROM messages m GROUP BY m._from HAVING (m._to!=0 AND m.group_1=0 AND m.group_2=0)

SELECT * FROM messages m WHERE m.group_1=m._from OR m.group_2=m._to;
```

I have a hard time understanding the relationship/purpose of group_1 and group_2 as well.

Single-query (by request by questioner)

```
SELECT * FROM messages m WHERE m.group_1=m._from OR m.group_2=m._to OR m.group_1=0 AND m.group_2=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry the explaining of groups, i have edited my question in order to try explain it better. Another thing, i will try with you query, but can it be turned into one query, instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `GROUP BY <field> HAVING <condition>`. Your "what needs to be done" is a bit chaotic and the group_1 and group_2 are confusing as well. Something you are looking for might be in the direction of:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     messages m
GROUP BY m.from HAVING (
    m.from = group_1 AND
    m.to   = group_2
)
```

I hope this will help you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried with the following: `GROUP BY messages.id HAVING (
    messages.group_1 = 0 AND
    messages.group_2 = 0
   )`, but it only comes out with the messages for the user conversations, and not for the groups.